# display product label on "out of stock " products

Tags: image, out-of-stock

I want to display a product label "out of stock" in frontend for those products which are set out of stock in the admin panel.

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: what you have tried till now ?

Comment: i searched for some extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-labels-6.html but it did't worked....

Comment: you want to show outofstock label on product on frontend or in admin ?

Comment: i want to to show in frontend....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $stockItem = $_product->getStockItem(); ?>
<?php if (!$stockItem->getIsInStock()): ?>
    <span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i placed that code in list.phtml and view.phtml , but it's not working, please guide me?

Comment: wer you had pasted can you show

Comment: you have to place the code in the foreach loop inside this loop foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>

Comment: please check here : http://pastebin.com/engLxxWc this is list.phtml , but still not displaying

Comment: may be because your listing product is in the grid mode and you added the code in the list mode.please try to put above code in the grid mode.you can see below in the same file

Comment: okay ,i wil try that......

Comment: similary show the code of the view.phtml

Comment: working ,its displaying in product -view page also , but in bottom, please tell me where to place the code in view .phtml = http://pastebin.com/qYf3SHb2

Comment: use css to place label on the image

Comment: i used css, but it's cutting the "out- of -stock " text when i used css : http://demo1.kidsdial.com/index.php/apparel.html

Answer (score 2):

To display the "out of stock" label on product view page, write the below code in the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$qty = $stock->getQty();
if($qty <= 0)
{
<span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
}
```

And if you want the label on the category page, write in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

**NOTE** : It is assumed that you are using magento-1.9 or greater

Comment: yes, i am using 1.9.0 , i wrote above code in both list and view.phtml files in custom theme.

Comment: still not achieved??

Comment: i've edited my answer

Comment: can you please tell me where i have to place your code here : http://pastebin.com/engLxxWc

Comment: after this line <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?> NOTE: this line occurs twice

Comment: okay, i will try.....

Comment: @Manashvibirla i tried like this :http://pastebin.com/thYuyiEd but it showing blank page

Comment: edited the answer, please check

Comment: This is a horrible answer, because you are making #products queries to the database, instead you should get all the stock data in one query and use them inside the loop.

Comment: @Manashvibirla thanks a lot for your support .

Comment: @TheMagentoKid yes, i got now.....

Comment: glad to help you :)